# HTTP PUT method in PHP: separating files from form data

Tags: php, api, rest, put

When a file is uploaded via POST, the form data is separated out from the file(s) via the $_POST and $_FILES variables (respectively). On the other hand, when a file is uploaded via PUT, the response must be retrieved from a single source (`php://input`). Unfortunately, when a file is involved, `php://input` seems to contain multiple headers, which appear to be divided by a key of some kind (`--6OJvloM5owOQsn2b3APr-Ad9dDLvRqBxm` in this case).

```
--6OJvloM5owOQsn2b3APr-Ad9dDLvRqBxm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="image.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<<<BINARY DATA>>>
--6OJvloM5owOQsn2b3APr-Ad9dDLvRqBxm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<<<FILE DESCRIPTION>>>
--6OJvloM5owOQsn2b3APr-Ad9dDLvRqBxm--
```

Short of iterating over the entire response and trying to pick out the different headers, is there a way to separate the files from the form data?

Note: I'm using a well-known 3rd-party application to make the API requests, so it's unlikely that the problem resides in the requests themselves.

Comment: That's a typical `multipart/form-data` request body, so that means the method is simply wrong; it should be sent with `POST`.

Comment: But I'd like a user to be able to update the image and description in a single request. Wouldn't PUT be the appropriate way to do that?

Comment: You could send the updated description as part of a request header, e.g. `X-Description: bla bla`.

Comment: No, that's a terrible idea. If the description and image are both constituent parts of the resource, then PUT is correct. Don't send anything in HTTP headers that are intrinsic parts of the entity you are acting upon. Only metadata such as dates goes in the headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to do to much in one PUT request. However, if you really need to handle the raw data, you should be able to parse it as a MIME string using a library such as this one: http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_mimeDecode

Comment: Are you saying that it is valid for a POST request to contain both a file and form data, but a PUT request must either contain one or the other? Is this part of the HTTP spec?